# Asynchronous Java: Help flatten my nested Mono

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Setup:

```
public Mono<Mono<String>> getAsyncResult() { // should return Mono<String>
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
        if (stopEarly()) return Mono.just("STOPPED EARLY");

        int a = doSyncJob1();
        int b = doSyncJob2();
        return doAsyncJob(a, b).map(string1 -> toString2(string1));
    });
}
```

Right now the whole thing returns `Mono<Mono<String>>`. How to get it to return `Mono<String>` without blocking?

The reason it's all inside `Mono.fromSupplier()` is because I don't need the tasks to necessarily block and happen immediately, they can be scheduled to run asynchronously. Maybe one way is to flatten what's inside `Mono.fromSupplier()` but I'm not sure how to compose it.

Comment: have you tried `Mono.fromSupplier(...).flatMap(Function.identity())`?

Answer (score 4):

Replace `Mono.fromSupplier` with `Mono.defer`

Also, if `doSyncJob*` blocks, then they will block the subscriber thread.  Therefore, you might want to use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())` after `.defer(...)` to ensure the blocking work is executed in a `Scheduler` meant for blocking work.

Comment: and here is the link to the documentation for reference https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking